# Why if matrix $A$ is invertible and $A(\mathbf{x-y})=0$ then $\mathbf{x-y}=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When browsing through my algebra textbook on examples of isomorhic linear transformation in one of the proofs there was a statement that if matrix $A$ is invertible and for vectors $\mathbf{x,y}$ it is true that $A(\mathbf{x-y})=0$ then $\mathbf{x-y}=0$. I'm just not seeing any connection between these statements. Why is this true?

Comment: Do you know what it means for a matrix to be invertible?

Comment: Apply $A^{-1}$ to the equation $Av=0$, then it follows $v=A^{-1}Av=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then you can assume that there exists a matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}\cdot A = 1$. Thus, from $A(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) = 0$ it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
A^{-1} \cdot A(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) &= A^{-1} \cdot 0 \\
1\cdot(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}) &= 0  \\
\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} & = 0.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to consider the general case: $$M(\mathbf x-\mathbf y) = 0 \iff \mathbf x-\mathbf y\in\ker M$$
Now what is $\ker M$ if $M$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to look at it. If $A$ is invertible, then it is one-to-one. This means that if $Ax=Ay$ then $x=y$, or $x-y=0$.

Alternatively, $A(x-y)=A 0$ implies $x-y=0$.